# svn: Checksum mismatch for ... .jar while checking out project

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

Lately when I try checking out some projects I regulary get the error

```
svn: Checksum mismatch for 'C:\workspaces\project\lib\some.jar':
   expected:  50a918dbdb1575a9749fe062a0621410
     actual:  244c77a12de55c4c739bc1ad90071fee
```

In the past I sometimes had this problem, while updating, but then usually some svn refresh fixed the issue. But now I can`t seem to successfully check out the project anymore.

The weird thing is: the library which causes the error seems to be random. Its not always the same library which causes the error. In some rare cases it even checks out completly.

I use the latest version of eclipse and subclipse. Collegues, who use subversive don't face this problem at all, but I'd prefer to continue with subclipse. Anyone has any suggestions, what could cause this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SVN checksums exist to catch corruption.  There could be legitimate corruption such as faulty RAM or network issue, but the more common explanation is a Windows anti-virus tool doing something to cause the problem.

It would not have anything specifically to do with Subclipse as it does not directly touch any of your files.  It calls API provided by SVN to do all of the "real work" that touches files or retrieves them from repository etc.

Comment: It was indeed an anti-virus tool. I`ve never seen that one coming, thanks a lot for pointing that out.